# Error in deserializing a compressed string (End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed) C#

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, compression, gzipstream

I am encountering exception **[System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.]** on de-serializing a string, please guide me what should I do to fix this error.

```
byte[] compressed;

string content = "afjsklf lkjflfkldsflkfj fa fj lflkf lk kj lkj fldsjf lkflewru pjdslk jsdfi;j klnvmlvnetu iowu lknxvmln3-958u09v lsn";

var compMS = new MemoryStream();
using (var compressor = new GZipStream(compMS, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(compressor, content);
    compressed = compMS.ToArray();
}

var decompMS = new MemoryStream(compressed);
using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(decompMS, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    decompMS.Position = 0;
    string result = (string)bf.Deserialize(decompMS);

}
```

I also tried to use `decompMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` but exception is still there.

http://dotnetfiddle.net/PF7egd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code.

- you execute compMS.ToArray() before you close the compressor (after the first using block)
- in decompression, you try to deserialize the raw data instead of the decompressed data

have a look at the new fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/OryftE

or the corrected code here:

```
byte[] compressed;

string content = "afjsklf lkjflfkldsflkfj fa fj lflkf lk kj lkj fldsjf lkflewru pjdslk jsdfi;j klnvmlvnetu iowu lknxvmln3-958u09v lsn";

var compMS = new MemoryStream();
using (var compressor = new GZipStream(compMS, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(compressor, content);
}

compressed = compMS.ToArray();

var decompMS = new MemoryStream(compressed);
using (var decompressor = new GZipStream(decompMS, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    decompMS.Position = 0;
    string result = (string)bf.Deserialize(decompressor);

}
```

Hope that helps.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: My issue was calling .ToArray() inside the using statement like you said.